# Serenity cross platform unified solution

Tags: java, selenium, guice-3

I am trying to make the existing solution to work on any platform. It's easy to make a custom driver extending the DriverSource class, but I still have to resolve the different page object injection (running on a mobile device for example has a different layout). For This I would like to use Google Guice

I am gonna share a solution without DI which works fine, but there should be a better way to to that.

```
public interface GooglePageInterface {

    public void enter_keywords(String keyword);

    public void lookup_terms();

    public void navigateToHomePage();
}
```

(You can use as well an abstract class instead of the interface as probably the most of the methods will be the same for mobile and desktop)

And the two implementations of the interface:

```
 public class GoogleMobilePage extends PageObject implements GooglePageInterface {

        @FindBy(name = "q")
        private WebElementFacade searchTerms;

        @FindBy(id = "tsbb")
        private WebElementFacade lookupButton;

        @Override
        public void enter_keywords(String keyword) {
            element(searchTerms).waitUntilVisible();
            searchTerms.sendKeys(keyword);
        }

        @Override
        public void lookup_terms() {
            lookupButton.click();
        }

        // demo purpose- there are better ways for this
        @Override
        public void navigateToHomePage() {
            getDriver().get("https://www.google.ro/");
        }
    }
```

and

```
 public class GoogleDesktopPage extends PageObject implements GooglePageInterface {

        @FindBy(name = "q")
        private WebElementFacade searchTerms;

        @FindBy(css = "button[name='btnG']")
        private WebElementFacade lookupButton;

        @Override
        public void enter_keywords(String keyword) {
            element(searchTerms).waitUntilVisible();
            searchTerms.sendKeys(keyword);
        }

        @Override
        public void lookup_terms() {
            lookupButton.click();
        }

        @Override
        public void navigateToHomePage() {
            System.out.println("You are in GoogleDesktopPage")
            getDriver().get("https://www.google.ro/");
        }
```

The AbstractSteps will decide base on a system property given in Cmd the imnplementation

```
public class AbstractSteps extends ScenarioSteps {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public GooglePageInterface getDictionaryPage() {

        switch (System.getProperty("runPlatform")) {

        case "desktop":
            return getPages().currentPageAt(GoogleDesktopPage.class);
        case "mobile":
            return getPages().currentPageAt(GoogleMobilePage.class);
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The EndUserStep will extend AbstractSteps and use the methods

```
public class EndUserSteps extends AbstractSteps{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Step
    public void enters(String keyword) {
        getDictionaryPage().enter_keywords(keyword);
    }

    @Step
    public void starts_search() {
        getDictionaryPage().lookup_terms();
    }

    @Step
    public void navigateToHomePage() {
        getDictionaryPage().navigateToHomePage();
    }

    @Step
    public void looks_for(String term) {
        enters(term);
        starts_search();
    }
}
```

And a basic test :

```
@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
public class SearchByKeywordStory {

    @Managed(uniqueSession = true)
    public WebDriver webdriver;

    @Steps
    public EndUserSteps endUserSteps;

    @Test
    public void searching_by_keyword_apple_should_display_the_corresponding_article() {
        endUserSteps.navigateToHomePage();
        endUserSteps.looks_for("something");
    } 
}
```

I run the test using the command :

mvn test -Dtest=SearchByKeywordStory -Dwebdriver.driver=provided -DrunPlatform=mobile -DrunEnv=staging-env verify,
where provided is the custom driver for mobile device :

```
public class CustomDriver implements DriverSource {

        @Override
        public WebDriver newDriver() {
            return setChromeMobile();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean takesScreenshots() {
            return true;
        }

        private WebDriver setChromeMobile() {
            Map<String, Object> deviceMetrics = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            //landscape
            deviceMetrics.put("width", 732);
            deviceMetrics.put("height", 412);
            deviceMetrics.put("pixelRatio", 3.0);
            Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            mobileEmulation.put("deviceMetrics", deviceMetrics);
            mobileEmulation.put("userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)                 Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Mobile Safari/537.36");
            Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
            return new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        }
    }
```

In serenity.properties

```
webdriver.driver=provided
webdriver.provided.type = mydriver
webdriver.provided.mydriver = com.tools.customerDrivers.CustomDriver
thucydides.driver.capabilities = mydriver
```

Done, it works!

But as I said before I want to try to make this work using Guice ,but I've encountered issues as Serenity instanciates the driver and the steps using Google Guice.

The page interface and the page implementations remain the same.

The step:

```
  public class EndUserSteps2 extends ScenarioSteps{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Inject
        GooglePageInterface  dictionaryPage;

        @Step
        public void enters(String keyword) {
            dictionaryPage.enter_keywords(keyword);
        }

        @Step
        public void starts_search() {
            dictionaryPage.lookup_terms();
        }

        @Step
        public void navigateToHomePage() {
            dictionaryPage.navigateToHomePage();
        }

        @Step
        public void looks_for(String term) {
            enters(term);
            starts_search();
        }
```

I've created a BaseTest where the injecor is created (this can be done in different ways)
The Module where the binding is done -bind(GooglePageInterface.class).to(GoogleDesktopPage.class)- can be in a differnt class

```
  @RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
    public class BaseTest {

        protected Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(GooglePageInterface.class).to(GoogleDesktopPage.class);
            }
        });

        @Before
        public void setup() {
            injector.injectMembers(this);
        }

    }
```

And the test:

```
@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
public class SearchByKeywordStory2 extends BaseTest {

    @Managed(uniqueSession = true)
    public WebDriver webdriver;

    //here is the issue
    @Inject
    @Steps
    public EndUserSteps2 endUserSteps;

    @Test
    public void searching_by_keyword_apple_should_display_the_corresponding_article() {
        endUserSteps.navigateToHomePage();
        endUserSteps.looks_for("something");
    }
}
```

The test starts but the driver is not passed to GoogleDesktopPage.class so the test fails but the class is injected as the message "You are in GoogleDesktopPage" from navigateToHomePage() is printed out

I know that Serenity injects the webdriver and the steps with the use of the annotations and I'm a bit stuck here

I would really appreciate if someone could help me to make this work somehow (probably a different approach with DI because this doesn't seem to be a good one)